# How to process final scrapers result in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

Say I am parsing a listing page and generating a JSON output. At the end when all stuff is parsed, I want to run some operations on final scraped result. How can i do it in Scrapy? I know about `process_item` but it works for each item in iteration. The closed thing I found was `close_spider` but I am not sure that if I run `scrapy crawl  spider` whether it will give me JSON I created in `closed_spider`? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass the `JsonItemExporter` overwriting the `finish_exporting` method to process the final json file

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer further. Do I get complete parsed data of ALL records in this method?

Comment: Hi @Volatil3 yes, basically the item exporter add the serialized items to the file, and because you have access to the output file, you have access to all the items (please check https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/exporters.py#L101) there the `file` variable is the file containing all the serialized items.  Alternatively you could also create a custom in-memory feed storage (the object in charge of storing the file used by the item exporter into its final destination like s3, ftp, etc), processing all the items when the method `store` is called